# Difference between C# and JSP

Tags: c#, jsp

What are the main difference between JSP and C#? Please reply guys, I searched on Google but the answers are  not so reliable. Please help friends!!

Comment: Not so reliable, like, "can you name the similarities?"

Comment: C# is a language and JSP are webpagesstands for Java server Pages

Comment: Similar to asking - "What's the difference[s] between ASP and Java?"

Comment: yah just like opensource and enterprise, like can you list out?

Comment: Not really. It's more along the lines of Lemons and MyersLemons - if MyersLemons have different tech bases than normal Lemons.

Answer (score 3):

C# is a language, JSP is a web-application framework for Java (both the Java language and thus the Java runtime).

A better comparison is to compare C# to Java (the language), ASP.NET to JSP, and .NET/CLR to Java (the runtime/VM).